# Check the condition of the current candle if an event happened before

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Please tell me where the following code went wrong (perhaps in plotchar) and how to fix it, it didn't show the char as I needed. Sincerely thank you.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Condition', overlay=false)
an1 = ta.ema(close, 50)
an2 = ta.ema(close, 200)
an3 = ta.ema(close, 20)
// Define variables to keep track of the last occurrence of the events
var last_an2_crossover_index = -1
var last_an1_crossover_index = -1
var last_valid_candle_index = -1

// Check if current candle meets the conditions
an2_crossover_index = ta.barssince(ta.crossover(an2, an3))
last_crossover_index = ta.barssince(ta.crossover(an1, an2))

can_display_arrow = an2_crossover_index == 0
var last_crossover_index_valid = last_crossover_index >= 0

// Check if previous candle met the conditions and mark it as processed
if last_an2_crossover_index == -1 and can_display_arrow
    last_an2_crossover_index := an2_crossover_index
else if last_an2_crossover_index >= 0 and last_an1_crossover_index == -1 and last_an2_crossover_index < an2_crossover_index and last_crossover_index_valid
    last_an1_crossover_index := last_crossover_index
    last_valid_candle_index := bar_index

// Set a variable to determine if an arrow should be displayed
condition = can_display_arrow and last_an2_crossover_index == an2_crossover_index and last_an1_crossover_index < last_an2_crossover_index and last_valid_candle_index == bar_index

// Display the arrow on the chart if the current candle meets the conditions and is the latest occurrence of the event
plotchar(condition, 'Current Candle', '☗', location.bottom, color=color.red)
```

Answer (score 1):

I interpret that *last_an2_crossover_index* will always be equal to 0
so, don't plot

```
var last_an2_crossover_index = -1
```

...

```
an2_crossover_index = ta.barssince(ta.crossover(an2, an3))
```

...

```
can_display_arrow = an2_crossover_index == 0
```

...

```
if last_an2_crossover_index == -1 and can_display_arrow
    last_an2_crossover_index := an2_crossover_index
```

Sorry for not giving you a solution, but I get lost in the if chain

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you have another way to find the first candle that reached condition A after the last event B?